# PHP SwiftMailer. Sending attachment with absolute path

Tags: php, timeout, swiftmailer

I'm using PHP SwiftMailer to send emails with attachment.

Everything works if attachment path is relative: 'dirname(**FILE**) . '/../../../archive/userfiles/invoices/a1d6bf13_Saskaita_137789.pdf'.

But on absolute path: 'http://185.38.166.110/userfiles/invoices/a1d6bf13_Saskaita_137789.pdf' I'm getting a message: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Connection to localhost:25 Timed Out'.

Where the problem could be?

Comment: you might not want to post that link on the internet as it looks like it contains personal information.

Comment: I found a solution. In php.ini file needs to set allow_url_fopen = on